# xfce keyboard layout panel plugin gets stuck

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, xfce, xkb

I use the xfce "Keyboard Layouts" panel plugin to switch between english and french layouts. Sometimes it gets stuck and clicking the button and alt-shift stops working. The only fix I have found is to open the keyboard settings and under the layouts tab, click one of the layouts and click the up/down button. The weird thing is it only happens on my laptop and not my desktop. Has anyone else experienced this?

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.10.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 27 08:28:22 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

'pacman -Q | grep xfce`:

```
gtk-xfce-engine 2.10.1-1
libxfce4ui 4.12.1-2
libxfce4util 4.12.1-1
xfce4-appfinder 4.12.0-4
xfce4-artwork 0.1.1a_git20110420-4
xfce4-battery-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-clipman-plugin 1.4.1-1
xfce4-cpufreq-plugin 1.1.3-1
xfce4-cpugraph-plugin 1.0.5-4
xfce4-datetime-plugin 0.7.0-1
xfce4-dev-tools 4.12.0-1
xfce4-dict 0.7.2-1
xfce4-diskperf-plugin 2.6.1-1
xfce4-eyes-plugin 4.4.5-1
xfce4-fsguard-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-genmon-plugin 4.0.0-1
xfce4-indicator-plugin 2.3.3-3
xfce4-mailwatch-plugin 1.2.0-7
xfce4-mount-plugin 1.1.2-1
xfce4-mpc-plugin 0.5.0-1
xfce4-netload-plugin 1.3.1-1
xfce4-notes-plugin 1.8.1-2
xfce4-notifyd 0.3.6-1
xfce4-panel 4.12.1-1
xfce4-power-manager 1.6.0.41.g9daecb5-1
xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin 0.2.4+8+g50c9279-1
xfce4-screenshooter 1.8.2-3
xfce4-sensors-plugin 1.2.6-3
xfce4-session 4.12.1-6
xfce4-settings 4.12.1-1
xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin 0.5.0-1
xfce4-systemload-plugin 1.2.1-1
xfce4-taskmanager 1.2.0-1
xfce4-terminal 0.8.4-1
xfce4-time-out-plugin 1.0.2-2
xfce4-timer-plugin 1.6.0-4
xfce4-verve-plugin 1.1.0-1
xfce4-wavelan-plugin 0.6.0-1
xfce4-weather-plugin 0.8.9-1
xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin 1.7.1-1
xfce4-xkb-plugin 0.7.1-2
```

Comment: I have the same exact problem on every restart. Sometimes it gets sorted out by itself. But I don't have fcitx installed, so the solution below doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was resolved by this:

1. Remove the hole file `fcitx` in `~/.config`.
2. Uncheck `auto-start fcitx`.
3. Reboot.

I think that fcitx missed up with the xfce settings.
Now xfce-settings will be set correctly.